# Month sorting in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In a database there is a table which contain the months like

```
 Month
------------
 MTH_01_2012
 MTH_02_2013
 MTH_03_2013
 MTH_04_2013
 MTH_05_2013
 MTH_01_2014
 MTH_03_2014
```

How can I retrieve the result in a descending way?

like output will be

```
Month
-----------
 MTH_03_2014
 MTH_01_2014
 MTH_05_2013
 MTH_04_2013
 MTH_03_2013
 MTH_02_2013
 MTH_01_2012
```

Comment: #winces#  All methods to sort this will ignore indices (As the current answer does).  In the long term, it'd be better to change what you're storing/how you're storing it, so you _could_ use an index.

Comment: Storing this as a `date` (with a check constraint to ensure, say, that the day part is always 1) would make this far easier to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY RIGHT([Month], 4) DESC , SUBSTRING([Month], 5, 2) DESC
```

Comment: I didn't see the answer and I wrote one almost as same as yours.. +1 to you :) 
But here is mine, 
**SELECT * 
FROM TEST
ORDER BY RIGHT(MYDATE,4) + SUBSTRING(MYDATE,5,2) DESC**

SQL FIDDLE: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/323be0/15

Comment: how can i use Distinct in your querY? @M.ALi

Answer (score 0):

use PARSENAME which inbuilt method to resolve your query.
try this one query instead of right and substring. it's cant give you exact word to order

```
Select *
From MonthMast
Order By 
    PARSENAME(Replace([MONTH],'_','.'), 1) DESC,
    PARSENAME(Replace([MONTH],'_','.'), 2) DESC
```

output is  :

```
Month
-------------
MTH_03_2014
MTH_01_2014
MTH_05_2013
MTH_04_2013
MTH_03_2013
MTH_02_2013
MTH_01_2012
```

check query. decide which query is best